# Old receiving address

Tags: bitcore

I sent my Bitcoin to an old address of mine but can’t figure out how to receive it I’ve the address is not open in my receiving tab but is under file receiving addresses

Answer (score 1):

> **can’t figure out how to receive it**

Once a transaction has been created by the sender, receiving Bitcoin requires no action whatsoever on the part of the recipient.

It is understandable that the recipient would like to have their wallet show them a received amount - but that is of no consequence in terms of transfer of control over an amount of money, The transfer either happened or it didn't. Regardless of whether your wallet knows about it or not.

So either the transfer happened and your wallet hasn't found out for some reason, or the transfer hasn't happened yet. The former can happen due to a wallet not being fully synchronised or not being able to communicate with other nodes. The latter can happen when the Bitcoin network is busy or when fees are set too low.

You can find out which is the case by putting the receiving address into a few Blockchain explorers.

---

> **the address is not open in my receiving tab but is under file receiving addresses**

That is normal. The receiving tab usually generates a new address for each transaction for privacy reasons.

---

Possibly related:

- [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/13866)